# Предзагрузка изображений в андроид студио?

Tags: android, изображения

В приложении на андроид выдаются рандомные изображения с сервера, по 2 штуки, после нажатия выдаются следующие и так далее. Проблема в том что они грузяться долго и нужно сделать, чтобы когда исчезают старые картинки на их месте появились новые без загрузки.

Comment: Загрузите сразу первые 6. Пока показываете №3 и №4 - грузите №7 и №8 и т.д.

Comment: а можно пример где-то посмотреть как это выглядит в коде?

Comment: А вы в запросе не указываете количество требуемых изображений и их номера?

Comment: Изображения могут повторяться?

Comment: картинки на хостинге, в базе ссылки на них и id. колличество не указано, пока не надоест, это типа игры. повторятся не должны.

Comment: Ну вот в запросе указывайте количество требуемых картинок и с сервера возвращайте столько, сколько было запрошено.

Comment: я пока плохо понимаю как это реализовать, но всё равно спасибо.